# Simple UDF to add space to a string

Tags: coldfusion

I am interested in creating a cold fusion UDF that will add a nonbreaking space to the beginning of a  string if the the number of characters in the string is 1 or less.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that lets all parameters be passed in instead of being hardcoded.

Useful if your might at some point want more than just `&nbsp;`, or could have different minimum lengths.

```
<cffunction name="prependIfShort" returntype="string" output="false">
    <cfargument name="String" type="string"  required />
    <cfargument name="Prefix" type="string"  required />
    <cfargument name="Limit"  type="numeric" required />

    <cfif len(Arguments.String) LTE Arguments.Limit >
        <cfreturn Arguments.Prefix & Arguments.String />
    <cfelse>
        <cfreturn Arguments.String />
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Using it as asked in the question is like this:

```
prependIfShort( Input , '&nbsp;' , 1 )
```

Name could probably be improved, but it's the best I could think of at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

```
function prependSpace(myString) {
  var returnString=myString;
  if (len(myString) LTE 1) {
    returnString="&nbsp;" & myString;
  }
  return returnString;
}
```

Comment: I've voted *this* one up because it'll work on all versions of CF from CF5 onwards, so strikes me as the solution with the most utility.  It's good to see all the varying approaches people have though.

Comment: I almost voted it down because the code had a bug, but I decided to fix it instead. :) However, if I was doing this I'd do a parameterised version, and not waste time creating a temp variable.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the fix. Yes, not as elegant as it could be, but certainly good enough to give the OP a place to start.

Answer (score 2):

To add some variety:

```
<cffunction name="padString" returnType="string" access="public" output="no">
    <cfargument name="input" type="string" required="yes">

    <CFRETURN ((len(ARGUMENTS.input) GT 1) ? ARGUMENTS.input : ("&nbsp;" & ARGUMENTS.input))>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// if using cf9+:
function padStr(str){
  return len(trim(str)) <= 1 ? 'nbsp;' & str : str
};
```

Comment: Why are you trimming the string?